# Uncomment code programmatically

Tags: c#, comments

How can I comment out some comment programmatically?
Think of something like this:-

```
void releaseA()
{
   //ToDo:
}
//string A = "Test";
releaseA();
textbox1.Text = A;
```

How can I achieve this and implement method `releaseA` to comment out `//string A = "Test";`
I searched but still can't find anything.

Comment: You want your code to be able to modify its own compiled code at runtime?

Comment: like in the same code that is currently executing?  Not gonna happen.  Is the code in a text file?  Just read it into a string or something and replace the //

Comment: I... what? I guess for what you are trying to achieve, you'd store some boolean flag and check that to determine what value for `A` you want to use. Is this for multi-platform compiling; something you could use [#if directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) to check for compilation targets?

Comment: it's just a sample guys, i want to know is there anyway to comment out a comment after compiled? for example if user check a checkbox then some comment, comment out and turn into code to do something...

Comment: There are better ways to accomplish that then by using comments - have the checkbox flip a boolean variable, and have that variable be used in a conditional statement which controls the expression of the dependent code.

Comment: With your comment, you're effectively describing the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).  You don't "uncomment/comment code" but instead switch states.

Comment: Even if this were possible it would be a horrible coding practice. Stick with logical control mechanisms(if, else, while, switch, ect)

Comment: `if user check a checkbox then some comment, comment out and turn into code to do something` What you're describing is conditional execution of code, otherwise known as an if-statement...

Comment: Not to mention that comments aren't even compiled into the DLL in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you really want to do is this:

```
string a = "";

if (condition)
    a = "Test";

textBox1.Text = a;
```

So for your example of a checkbox and a text box:

```
string text = "";

if (checkBox.Checked)
    text = inputTextBox.Text;

resultTextBox.Text = text;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to comment code before a build of the specified file you can work with compiler switches and specify the compiler switch when building the file in VS or with MSBuild.

You can use something like this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
//string A = "Test";
#else
string A = "Test";
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that comments are ignored by the compiler and won't be resident in the overall exe. So this would technically be impossible, given your current code.

Besides, you'd have no reference to which 'line' said code would be on once its compiled to bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't code in c#, but do a bit in c & Objective C, so i am sure this approach is portable.

if i have a feature i want to be able to conditionally enable at compile time, and potentially disable it at runtime (not the other way around!), i use the following approach.

**In a global (prefix) header** that all relevant files will see (or a command line switch), define a constant that forces the **compiler** to physically include the feature's code into the executable. this is effectively a bool constant.

```
#define acme_support        1
```

**In a common header file** (eg settings.h) define a wrapper around this which tells the runtime 
code if the feature is available. if it's not available, it's hard coded. if it is available, it's an external bool.

```
#if acme_support
extern bool runtime_acme_support;
#else
#define runtime_acme_support 0
#endif
```

in the **implementation file** associated with "settings.h" (lets call it "settings.c"):

```
#if acme_support
bool runtime_acme_support = 1;
#endif
```

Then throughout your project where you want to include code for the feature:

```
#if acme_support

    if (runtime_acme_support) {

        /*  process the acme widgets for the acme store. */

    }

#endif
```

As you can see, the `#if`  /  `#endif` prevents disabled code being enabled if it was not included at compile time, but you can still "disable" the feature at runtime if certain conditions require that (for example required hardware is not present)

Note that's an `#if` not a `#ifdef`, as `#ifdef` will still be true since '0' is still "defined", whereas `#if` is a boolean test on the value '0' / '1' which is false/true respectively.

Comment: obviously to disable acme widget store support in this example you'd use `runtime_acme_support = 0;` somewhere in your code.